# Where is a link to javadoc for the Eclipse WST Validation Framework?

Tags: validation, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-wtp

I have searched, but the closest I can find is https://eclipse.dev/webtools/wst/components/validation/ValidationFrameworkAPI.html.  Where is a link to the full javadoc with listings of classes, methods, parameters, etc.?

Comment: The sources of Eclipse plugins are usually provided in separate source plugins which should be part of your target platform when developing an Eclipse plugin.

Comment: Hover to see javadoc isn't working, so I assume the source plugins are not installed with the code plugin.  The repository link given in https://eclipse.dev/webtools/wst/components.html returns 404 or page isn't working.  Looking at the Install new software... options, I couldn't find anything.  Many Eclipse projects provide javadoc online, e.g., https://archive.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/javadoc/2.6/overview-summary.html

Comment: The motivating question is to find javadoc about default handling of XML validation errors.  Validation errors currently result in IWorkspace IResourceChange POST_CHANGE events, where the event data is not sufficient to distinguish in-memory editing validation errors from changes when saving file resources.

Comment: About what plugin you are talking? `org.eclipse.wst.validation`? If yes, that's also part of the simultaneous release, e.g. https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2023-12/ Please show your target platform. Having the sources in Eclipse is much better than browsing Javadoc online, isn't it?

Comment: I am using 2022-03.  I installed Eclipse Web Developer Tools and Eclipse XSL Developer Tools (which said it had the validator).  On restart, my Eclipse configuration went into an infinite loop of popups "Requesting AST from selection" and error has occurred 'boolean com.ibm.icu.text.UTF176.isSurrogate(char)', blocking any use of my development environment.  Fortunately, I was able to revert to a working configuration.  So I'm back to hunting for an online copy of the javadoc for the validation framework.

Comment: I don't know if and if so where the Javadoc of `org.eclipse.wst.validation` is available online. [The sources of the latest `org.eclipse.wst.validation` plugin which contains the Javadoc comments are available e.g. here](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/releases/2023-12/202312061001/plugins/org.eclipse.wst.validation.source_1.3.0.v202308161955.jar). Eclipse 2022-03 is seven releases behind. Please upgrade.